Who's more like to win the game of ludo
A and B have been playing ludo for many hours both have 3 pieces in home and each has 1 piece left on the board. They decide to call it quits due to the lack of time. But they first have to decide who would likely have won if they continued playing. A says he's only 2 away from home while B is 4 away, making him more likely to have won. B retorts, saying that the possibility of 4 appearing in a die throw is equal to that of 2.
(PS: If you roll a die greater than your distance from home, it's negated and the die is passed to your opponent)
Now I think B won because there are more ways for him to go to the home
Like (4),(1,3),(1,1,2)... While for A it's only (1,1) and (2)
Can you calculate, if they played for at most 4 die-throws, how many times each ends up winning?

Perhaps it would be helpful if you wrote out the rules of the game....not sure everyone here is familiar with it.  We don't need the full set of rules, just enough to see what the various paths to victory look like.  For instance, do we need to know whose turn is next?

The key element here is: both players win in each round with probability $\frac{1}{6}$, regardless of their previous moves and their positions (why?). Then it's the standard which geometric distribution hits first type of question, with a limit of $4$ rounds..

@lulu Pawn Movement
Navigation of the pawns on the board is done corresponding to the score the player gets on his dice every turn. For example, a score of three on the dice means the player can move the token (pawn) up by three places on the board. Every player starts the game with four tokens in their respective starting zones. The first player to eject all tokens from the starting zone and successfully navigate them into the end zone is declared the winner. A pawn enters the home zone when it completes its entire track, i.e. from the starting point to its respective coloured home area.


Ludo is a game with sequential throws, not simultaneous throws.

As long as both are within $\leq6$ spots away from Home, the Pr of a winning throw is  $\frac16$

So the person whose turn it is to throw first has winning odds of $\frac16:\frac56\frac16= 6:5$

So suppose $A$ throws first, P(A wins) $= \frac6{11}$



Added
That is with game proceeding until some one wins
If you limit the game to a total of $4$ throws ($2$ throws each),
P(A wins) $=\frac16 +[\frac56]^2\frac16 = \frac{61}{216}=\frac{366}{1296}$
P(B wins) $= \frac56\frac16 + [\frac56]^3\frac16 = \frac{305}{1296}$
Odds that A wins $= 366:305 = 6:5$
which shows explicitly that limitng the rounds doesn't affect the odds, but of course, the probabiities of one or the other winning won't add up to $1$,
P(A wins) $= \frac{366}{1296} = \frac{61}{216},\approx 28.24\%$
P(wins) $= \frac{305}{1296}, \approx 23.53\%$
P(game inconclusive) $= \frac{625}{1296}, \approx 48.23\%$

Are you having any doubts ? If so, feel free to ask.
